# How to layout sidebar and main body without using 'absolute' or 'float'?

Tags: css, xhtml, html

I can't for the life of me find a way to make this work.

If I have 3 divs (a left sidebar, a main body, and a footer), how can I have the sidebar and main body sit next to each other without setting their positions as "absolute" or floating them? Doing either of these options result in the footer div not being pushed down by one or the other.

How might I accomplish this regardless of what comes before these elements (say another header div or something)?

In case it helps, here's an illustration of the two cases I'm trying to allow for:

[image]

Here's a simplified version of the HTML I currently have set up:

```
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to specify the footer to clear the float:

```
#footer{
 clear: both;
}
```

This forces it under floated elements.

Other options for clear are left and right.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what was needed! I tried using clear but on the floated divs rather than the footer, now it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Doing either of these options result in the footer div not being pushed down by one or the other?

Try [this tool](http://www.pagecolumn.com/2_column_div_generator.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're pretty hopeless if you don't want to float anything, nor use position: absolute.

The only alternatives left are:

- use display:inline-block for the sidebar and content divs (this is not supported by all browsers yet)
- wait for the [css advanced layout module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-layout) or some other column module (will take forever probably)
- go back to using tables